# Is this below static method thread safe? Can someone guide me on how to make it thread safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, thread-safety

I referred to many articles to learn about thread-safety. But finally in a confused state, so thought to seek expert advice.

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a string. I got two methods `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` in the `EncryptDecrypt` class and I need to use it in many classes. So instead of creating an instance and each class, can I create a static method like below and will it be thread-safe?

```
public static string Decrypt(string input)
{
    string decrypted = "";
    try
    {
        EncryptDecrypt crypto = new EncryptDecrypt();
        decrypted = crypto.AESDecrypt(input);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("failed", ex);
    }
    return decrypted;
}
```

Can someone guide me through? Or please refer any good articles about thread-safety.

Comment: You are creating new instances of each class in your function, so this is thread-safe, threading problems arise when multiple threads access the same objects. Unless your `EncryptDecrypt` class shares objects among it's instances, you're safe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It will be thread-safe because you are passing different input values for all the threads and there will be different scope for each and every function.